# What is the meaning of "Integral a => Enum (Ratio a)" in documentation of haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am having difficulty reading the Haskell documentation of `Data.Ratio` ([link](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/libraries/base/Data-Ratio.html)). 
What is the meaning of an instance `Integral a => Enum (Ratio a)` of `data Ratio a`? I read about the declaration of instances but did not find any example that have `=>` while declaring an instance.

Comment: You appear to be a Haskell beginner. Before asking questions like this, I'd strongly suggest you read [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) to completion. This question is covered within that book, namely [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-102).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Integral a => Enum (Ratio a)` simply means that we require `a` to be an instance of the typeclass `Integral` when we declare the instance for `Enum (Ratio a)`.

That is, if `Ratio a` is an instance of `Enum`, then we must have that `a` is an instance of `Integral`.

Here is a simplified example, with a silly datatype:

```
data Representation a = R a

instance Show a => Eq (Representation a) where
  (R a) == (R b) = show a == show b
```

Notice how my restriction of `a` being a member of `Show` allows me to use the `show` function. A similar thing happens in the declaration of `Enum (Ratio a)`.